# Are retail sales of a particular product affected by mixing goods from different manufacturers?

Tags: virtonomics

Suppose I have a store, and I want to sell bread. Suppose there are two bread factories I can buy from. Factory A is owned by company A, factory B is owned by factory B. Assuming that the bread from company A and B both have the same quality and brand rating, I could do one of these:

1. Sell company A's bread exclusively
2. Sell company B's bread exclusively
3. Sell a mix of company A's and company B's bread

Will there be any difference in retail sales between the three choices above? If so, what causes the difference?